# Connectives in George Tourlakis' Mathematical Logic

Tags: logic

In page 10 of Mathematical Logic, Tourlakis says that "Readers who have done some elementary course in logic, or in the context of a programming course, may have learned that ¬, ∨ are the only connectives one really *needs* since the rest can be expressed in terms of these two."

[Capture from the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2JQg.png)

**How can we express the other connectives (→, ∧, ≡)** using only ¬ and ∨?

[Capture from the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4vGH.png)

Comment: What have you tried? Some of these are pretty simple (look at the truth tables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following logical equivalences (or equations in Boolean algebra) can be checked in a variety of ways:
\begin{align}
P \wedge Q & = \neg (\neg P \vee \neg Q) \\
P \to Q & = \neg P \vee Q \\
P \leftrightarrow Q & = (P \to Q) \wedge (Q \to P) \\
& = (\neg P \vee Q) \wedge (\neg Q \vee P) \\
& = \neg\bigl( \neg (\neg P \vee Q) \vee \neg (\neg Q \to P)\bigr)
\end{align}
The first, for example, can be considered as using De Morgan's Law, but could also be verified using truth tables.